# PHP if statement execute both if and ELSE if

Tags: php

as you can see by my code, if the variable $uname and $password are not equal to the values they should be in the text file im reading from, it should print and error. Unfortunately it does not. When the values are correct however it prints both the success message and the failure message on the same line instead of just the success message. I am sure I'm overlooking something very simple but still need to ask. The code is below. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $password = sha1($pass);
    $filename = "pass.txt";
    $contents = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
    foreach ($contents as $value) {
        $details = explode(':', $value);
        if ($uname == $details[0]&& $password == $details[1]) {
          echo" Welcome, Access Has Been Granted!";
        }  else {
          echo "Please Check User Name and Or Password";
          exit;
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Is there more code in this file that could be doing the printing?  I don't think `if/else` is broken.

Comment: You're performing this operation in a loop.  How have you determined that the `if` block and the `else` block are not executing on separate iterations of that loop?  Seems ***far*** more likely than `if/else` being fundamentally broken as you propose.

Comment: Use a `break;` to exit the foreach loop after find the user.

Answer (score 1):

Your password check is inside a loop, and that loop will repeat for every line in `pass.txt` -- even if a line is totally empty. You should modify your code so that a `$password_success` variable defaults to `FALSE` and is only set to true if a valid, matching user/password line exists. Then, outside the loop, check `$password_success` exactly once.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $password = sha1($pass);
    $filename = "pass.txt";
    $contents = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
    $password_success = FALSE;
    foreach ($contents as $value) {
        $details = explode(':', $value);
        if (sizeof($details) == 2) {
            if ($uname == $details[0]&& $password == $details[1]) {
                $password_success = TRUE;
                break; // this will stop our password file looping
            }
        } else {
            // skip invalid password file line

        }
    }

    if ($password_success) {
      echo" Welcome, Access Has Been Granted!";
      exit;
    }  else {
      echo "Please Check User Name and Or Password";
      exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JacobSBaker you're welcome. feel free to select my answer as the solution. i'm all about the points!